# How can I tell if I've applied deodorant?

Tags: personal-care

I used to get scented deodorant so I was able to smell the fragrance under my arm and know that it was applied. But unfortunately the brand I use has discontinued the scented version and I must now use an unscented version. Often I can't remember whether it's been applied, and end up applying it again to be sure although it's likely that it had already been applied. There may be times when I have applied deodorant three or four times.

> **How can I know for a certainty if I have already applied unscented deodorant / antiperspirant?**

*Note: The type that I am using is in the form of a roll-on stick.*

Comment: Is the deodorant a dry kind because if its not then you can probably feel it

Comment: It's roll-on. Though it dries I'm unable to see it. I try very hard.

Comment: While not fool proof, develop and then stick to a routine. I'm awesome at forgetting things like this so at both home and the gym all my shower stuff is a bag (soap, shampoo, comb, q-tips, deodorant, etc). Before or after the shower, I take all the stuff in the bag out that I want to use. As you use the stuff after the shower, immediately put it back into the bag. There are additional benefits as well to this as it makes your area more attractive and less time actively searching for and then cleaning up the items you used.

Comment: This seems like a trivial "problem". If you *really* can't be sure, just apply it again as you are leaving the house (or whatever). There is no harm in doing so, unless you count the negligible cost of a single dose of deodorant. If this is happening so often that the costs *are* mounting, you should probably just change to a scented brand.

Comment: As a pedant, I think you should be clear if you are talking about anti-perspirant or deodorant, as they're different things, and mixing them up causes problems for people who don't realize this ("Why am I sweating when I've used deodorant.")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is going to sound weird so don't judge me.

I am assuming it is antiperspirant (otherwise it defeats the point of having non-fragrant) so once it is applied, if you rub your fingers or hand in your armpits and then lick them (weird part). If the antiperspirant has been applied then it should feel really dry on your tongue and your fingers should almost stick to your tongue momentarily. If there is none applied it will be slightly unpleasant but you will have your answer.

Comment: You are correct, that was incredibly weird. It's something I never would have thought of though, and sometimes those are the best answers.

Comment: Did your tongue really dry out from your deodorant? Hard to believe this as saliva is not being produced by the tongue, and I would be somewhat worried to put such a powerful chemical on my tongue (or skin).

Comment: @Takkat well the mouth is a generally wet place where your tongue is the most and the tongue can sense wet and can sense dry so if I goes from being wet to dry (as antiperspirant absorbs moisture) you'll be able to feel it dry your tongue off! That's the whole point of antiperspirant - anti sweat - sweat is wet - absorbs wet and keeps pits dry. Would dry your mouth out if your sprayed it/ rolled it in there (highly ill advised)

Comment: [Antiperspirants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deodorant) directly block sweat production through action on the sweat glands but they do not absorb moisture. Deodorants on the other hand contain antimicrobial substances but do not act on sweat production. That's why I was so confused about your observation that the tongue dried out.

Comment: @Takkat oh I just assumed they did for the reason it dries out - also trying to shower directly after applying it feels dry / sticky to try an get off!

Answer (score 5):

You can touch your armpits and notice the texture.

Alternatively, you can develop the habit of putting the deodorant in front of the door after you use it. That way, if it's in its place, you know you haven't used it yet. And this system is self-resetting, because when you go out in the morning, you must replace the deodorant where it belongs before you pass through the door.

Comment: Programming is a good idea. The way I resolve my issue is to always follow the same steps with the towel, deodorant, and anything else upon getting out of the shower. If the wife speaks to me I ignore her, to avoid being distracted. This is a critical time!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the surface of your roll-on stick:

- **Dull and dry surface:** the roll-on was not used in the last 10 minutes.

  [image]
- **Glossy and wet surface:** you had used it recently.

  [image]

The amount of containing fluid may however vary between brands, so it may not always be that obvious.

Alternatively and in case your container was transparent you could also watch for a fluid level in the container:

- **No level visible:** the deodorant was evenly distributed on the inner surface of the container. Due to the high viscosity it will take some time to settle. You had used or moved it recently.
- **Fluid level visible:** (on the botom when stored upright, at the sides when stored lying) the deodorant was not used recently.

Comment: The ball on the roll-on stick always looks the same whether or not recently used. The screw-on cap prevents it from drying out. The container is not transparent, so it's impossible to see inside.

Comment: Well, my stick's surface does dry out after a while despite me always closing the cap. I know, because I sometimes use exactly this to check whether I had used it or not... it may be that this varies from brand.

Comment: I've tried to find something distinguishable on the roll-on stick. One would think something should be apparent. But I like my brand of deodorant and refuse to change.

Comment: Added live shots to demonstrate better what my stick does.